# How to fix "A form label must be associated with a control" ? ESlint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have read that htmlFor needs to be added to fix this error, but even with this piece of code, ESlint gives me an error. How can I fix this?

```
        <input readOnly type="radio" name="slider-2" id="s1-2" checked />
        <input readOnly type="radio" name="slider-2" id="s2-2" />
        <input readOnly type="radio" name="slider-2" id="s3-2" />

        <label type="text" htmlFor="s1-2" id="slide1-2">
          <div className="slider-image">
            <img src={SecendQadroFirst} alt="qadro" />
          </div>
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="s2-2" id="slide2-2">
          <div className="slider-image">
            <img src={SecendQadroSecend} alt="qadro" />
          </div>
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="s3-2" id="slide3-2">
          <div className="slider-image">
            <img src={SecendQadroThird} alt="qadro" />
          </div>
        </label>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the inputs inside their corresponding labels?

Comment: Duplicate of [Label must have associated control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62306461/215552) (don't have the votes to close).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Label must have associated control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306461/label-must-have-associated-control)

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the input between the label itself and ensure that you have the htmlFor attribute for the label.

```
<label type="text" htmlFor="s1-2" id="slide1-2">
   <div className="slider-image">
      <img src={SecendQadroFirst} alt="qadro" />
   </div>
   <input readOnly type="radio" name="slider-2" id="s1-2" checked />
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

The attribute you want in the `<label>` element is simply `for`, and the value must be the id of the `<input>` element it is associated with. The input should be after the `</label>` closing tag

```
<label type="text" for="s1-2" id="slide1-2">
   <div className="slider-image">
      <img src={SecendQadroFirst} alt="qadro">
   </div>
</label>
<input readOnly type="radio" name="slider-2" id="s1-2" checked>

<label for="s2-2" id="slide2-2">
   <div className="slider-image">
      <img src={SecendQadroSecend} alt="qadro">
   </div>
</label>
<input readOnly type="radio" name="slider-2" id="s2-2">
        
        
<label for="s3-2" id="slide3-2">
   <div className="slider-image">
       <img src={SecendQadroThird} alt="qadro">
   </div>
</label>
<input readOnly type="radio" name="slider-2" id="s3-2">
```

Comment: This is JSX not HTML